# Sharing wired network

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have a wired connection over a proxy server, and I'd like to share it over wireless to my other laptop. Is there some software or something that allows me to do this? I am using ubuntu 12.04 on the machine with wired Internet connection and windows 7 on other.

(It is diffferent from previously asked question as that is for home network not behind proxy server and my question is about the network behind proxy)

Comment: The proxy makes no difference to the question, AFAIK.

Comment: But I am not able to get internet connection on other after following these steps.

Comment: Then please state exactly what you have tried, what failed and how and click ask for reopen. But without new information it is the same question. Or you can try the Ubuntu Forums, maybe it's format is better for you than the question-answer way we use here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it is really easy using ubuntu, the only thing is that your ubuntu machine will need a wifi card to act as a personal hotspot.

Here is a link to a tutorial that works, hope it helps.

http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/

Comment: Thanks for reply but it is not working as I am behind the proxy, The procedure share my PC with other computer but not the internet.